# Jmeter - java exception while clicking on response in View Results Tree

Tags: java, exception, jmeter

I'm facing this issue: 
Once a test plan has completed, if there are errors, when I click on the red row, I got this exception in the log:

```
    2018-07-18 15:15:03,837 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.desktop/javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$DefaultDocumentEventUndoableWrapper cannot be cast to java.desktop/javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$DefaultDocumentEvent
    at jsyntaxpane.CompoundUndoMan.undoableEditHappened(CompoundUndoMan.java:61) ~[jsyntaxpane-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireUndoableEditUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:293) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleRemove(AbstractDocument.java:632) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.remove(AbstractDocument.java:596) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setText(JEditorPane.java:1422) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.SamplerResultTab.clearData(SamplerResultTab.java:202) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.SamplerResultTab.setupTabPane(SamplerResultTab.java:222) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.valueChanged(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:387) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.valueChanged(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:365) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(JTree.java:2968) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(JTree.java:3457) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:641) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:1111) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:297) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:191) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPath(JTree.java:1657) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.selectPathForEvent(BasicTreeUI.java:2736) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(BasicTreeUI.java:4015) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTreeUI.java:3954) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6586) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6354) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2261) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4966) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2319) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4914) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4540) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4484) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2305) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(EventQueue.java:97) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
```

have you any idea on how to fix it?

MAC OSX High Sierra 
Jmeter 4.0 r1823414
java 10.0.1 2018-04-17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this may be an issue with Jmeter not yet supporting Java 10.  This was a similar issue that was reported against Jmeter 3.x without support for Java 9 [Bug 61529](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61529).  I would suggest trying to run with Java 9 and then I believe you will avoid this issue.

Comment: omg thank you!  running with an older version of Java worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. I have logged in a [bug on the Apache Bugzilla here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63360). Please vote for this bug.

Someone suggested there that I **downgrade** from JMeter 5.1.1 to version [4.0 that can be found here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/). I tried it and it worked!